# The verb opposite to 'come in'

Tags: antonyms, phrase-requests

I am looking for an expression how to ask *'leave the classroom for several minutes to call somebody or to blow my nose, etc.'* We usually use such an expression 'May I  come in' when we would like to enter the room and I am looking for its antonym. Is it suitable to use 'go out/go off' for this purpose? I mean 'to leave the room for several minutes and then go back.'

Comment: 'May I come in?' is a stand-alone expression. But a stand-alone request wouldn't normally be acceptable in a classroom situation. 'Please(,) may I go to the toilet?' provides the reason most teachers would deem necessary. 'Please may I leave the room to phone my friend?' gives a reason that most teachers would not accept under normal circumstances.

Comment: What is wrong with the phrase *May I leave?*?

Comment: What @EdwinAshworth said. But if you feel you need to avoid providing background/detail about what you intend to do or why, you can ask *May I please leave?* The teacher might wonder why, but if s?he senses your seriousness or embarassment then s?he might well not ask why.

Answer (score 4):

**May I be excused?**

> *May I be excused?*  - May I leave this place, please?; May I leave to use the toilet?
>
> *Nature calls. **May I be excused**?*
>
> *The student raised her hand and said, "Teacher, **may I be excused**?"*
>
> [McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/May+I+be+excused%3F).

[image]

Comment: Very good.  You may also say "step out" or "step out of the room [for a moment]", or "step into the hall [for a moment]."